# How to compute size of soap message body in JAVA

Tags: java, soap, jax-ws

I have a requirement of compressing Soap Request if the size of soap request if greater than 200KB. Could you please tell if there is a way to determine Soap body size in JAVA?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by determining content length of Soap Body.